# python post request throwing '400 Bad Request'

Tags: python

I am trying to execute below script where I try to send POST request. I have replaced some values in headers part in order to post it here. The issue I have is related to body of my request which I read from xmlFile.xml. File is in the same directory as my script. XML is written in one line and begins with following line:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Could you please help? I cannot understand why it is returning 400 Bad Request. XML separately is working fine, but not from within the py script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import httplib

def do_request(xmlFile):
    request = open(xmlFile, "r").read()
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("ipAddress", port)
    conn.putrequest("POST", "selector HTTP/1.1")
    conn.putheader("Content-Length", "%d" % len(request))
    conn.putheader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
    conn.putheader("Host", "ipAddress")
    conn.putheader("User-Agent", "userAgent")
    conn.endheaders()

    conn.send(request)

    response = conn.getresponse()
    print(response.status, response.reason)
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()

do_request('xmlFile.xml')
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate "XML seperately is working fine" ?

Comment: I have connected to host and sent XML via telnet and response was as expected HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC the second argument to `putrequest()` should be the `path` part of the url (`/` for the root). **But** you're making it much more complicated than it has to be - you could use `conn.request(method, path, params, headers)` [as showed here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#examples), or (even better) just use `python-requests` actually (even the official httplib doc recommend it).

Comment: Thank you for your comment and suggestion. Yes, you are right, issue was due to protocol type `HTTP/1.1 ` written in `putrequest()` After removing it, the requset was OK